# Azure Mobile Apps post body empty with body-parser

Tags: node.js, azure-mobile-services

I have consistently had problems getting the post body of a custom API.  I got it working briefly after adding body-parser to my package.json and running npm install, but now I am faced with request.body not having any data in it throughout my application.

In my app.js, I register the body parser with the following lines of code.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));
```

In my custom api sitting in the API folder, I have something like this.

```
    post: (request, response, next) => {
    var body = request.body;
    var context = request.azureMobile; }
```

request.body comes up empty every time.  I've tried it with JSON and form parameters. Neither works.  In this example, I am running locally but doesn't work when I push it to Azure either.   I've tried new projects, different API files, other suggestions in stackoverflow.  I am at a loss.  Something so simple shouldn't be this complicated.

Comment: At what point are you adding the body parser middleware in app.js? It must be mounted before the mobile apps middleware is mounted. Incidentally, what version of the mobile apps SDK are you using? We added automatic body parsing to custom APIs some time ago.

Comment: Ok here is what I discovered.  It appears the issue is isolated to code running locally.  Seems to work fine in Azure.  In this case I am debugging in Visual Studio Code.  Mobile apps version is 3.0.1.  It will work for a while and then it stops.  I uninstall and reinstall the bodyparser package and then debug again and it will work.  I noticed that when I have extremely large post bodies, if I remove it and post something small, it will start to work from there on.  Very odd indeed.  Happens on multiple computers for me too.

Answer (score 0):

As @Dale mentioned earlier, as of today, we do not need to install *body-parser* middleware to get the POST body of a custom API in Azure mobile apps. My guess is that you'd missed *Content-Type* in your request header.

The following is my test result:

***testBody.js***

```
module.exports = {

    "post": function (req, res, next) {
        res.send('request body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    }
}
```

---

[image]